# Find Important predictors in a model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection

I want to analyze and solve a few questions from the very famous project called red wine quality analysis which is freely available in the following link:
 https://www.kaggle.com/piyushgoyal443/red-wine-analysis/data

The problem is to Find the 2 most important predictors of red wine quality.

I have proceeded with using ols_all_step_possible() function in olsrr package in R. In the result part it gives a dataframe of each and every combination of the predictors with the model and its rsquare, Adj.rsquare, AIC, fpe,.......

I have found out that alcohol and volatile acidity are the two best predictors based on high Adj.rsquare and low (AIC, fpe) from the result:

Results

[Result file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5circ.png)

My question is whether looking at rsquare and AIC of the model is enough to say that those variables(included in the model and there p-values are significant) are important predictors ? Or, we have to divide it into train test sets and see the test MAPE and then decide it's important predictor or not ?

Comment: What is your question?  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Edit your question to include this.  Do not post details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about the methods to find out the best predictors. You can make use of various methods to find out the best predictors. For finding the predictors, you should use feature selection. You can follow the link:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-the-caret-r-package/

One more thing R-square, Adj R - square are the parameters which define the quality of model not the indibidual predictors. Yes you can see that on the basis of P-value.
Same goes for AIC. These are most useful for selection between two models.
Model with higher r-square is better than with the lesser one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was making a mistake assuming that Rsquare parameter might be used to explain the importance of the variable but instead its the model result.